# Как закропить центральную часть картинки в блоке?

Tags: html, css, изображения

Есть блоки с картинками, которые должны быть одинаковые по размеру (максимально 248 на 128, а при малых разрешениях занимать всю ширину), даже если изображение больше блока. Как закропить центральную часть картинку в блоке, чтобы она не растягивалась или сужалась, но всегда была видна центральная ее часть?

```css
.front {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 246px;
  max-height: 128px;
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.front img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: -160px;
}
```

```html
<div class="front"><img src="http://kaifolog.ru/uploads/posts/2010-06/1275372790_001.jpeg" width="644" height="724"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример

```css
.front {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 246px;
    max-height: 128px;
    /*height: 1px;*/
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}

.front img {
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="front"><img src="http://kaifolog.ru/uploads/posts/2010-06/1275372790_001.jpeg" width="644" height="724"></div>
```